# Datepicker not firing when add new row in datatables

Tags: datatables

When clicking the add new row i want a date picker calendar should appear i tried using jquery easy ui
But when i click the datepicjker id field its not firing below is the code .

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "demo_page.css";
        @import "demo_table.css";
        td input { width: 100% }
        #example_wrapper { min-height: 0; }
    </style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery- ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"   src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
     <script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Here is the javascript code

```
    function restoreRow ( oTable, nRow )
        {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
            var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);

            for ( var i=0, iLen=jqTds.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ) {
                oTable.fnUpdate( aData[i], nRow, i, false );
            }

            oTable.fnDraw();
        }

        function editRow ( oTable, nRow )
        {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
            var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
            jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[0]+'">';
            jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="'+aData[1]+'">';
            jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[2]+'">';
            jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[3]+'">';
            jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+aData[4]+'">';
            jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a>';
        }

        function saveRow ( oTable, nRow )
        {
            var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false );
            oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false );
            oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false );
            oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false );
            oTable.fnUpdate( jqInputs[4].value, nRow, 4, false );
            oTable.fnUpdate( '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 5, false );
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
            var nEditing = null;

            $('#new').click( function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var aiNew = oTable.fnAddData( [ '', '', '', '', '', 
                    '<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', '<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>' ] );
                var nRow = oTable.fnGetNodes( aiNew[0] );
                editRow( oTable, nRow );
                nEditing = nRow;
            } );

            $('#example a.delete').live('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
                oTable.fnDeleteRow( nRow );
            } );

            $('#example a.edit').live('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                /* Get the row as a parent of the link that was clicked on */
                var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

                if ( nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow ) {
                    /* Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
                    restoreRow( oTable, nEditing );
                    editRow( oTable, nRow );
                    nEditing = nRow;
                }
                else if ( nEditing == nRow && this.innerHTML == "Save" ) {
                    /* Editing this row and want to save it */
                    saveRow( oTable, nEditing );
                    nEditing = null;
                }
                else {
                    /* No edit in progress - let's start one */
                    editRow( oTable, nRow );
                    nEditing = nRow;
                }
            } );
        } );
    </script>
</head>
```

And html table

```
   <body id="dt_example">
   <div id="container">
   <div id="demo">
      <p><a id="new" href="">Add new row</a></p>
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
   <thead>
   <tr>
<th>Rendering engine</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Platform(s)</th>
<th>Engine version</th>
<th>CSS grade</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>23rd june</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center"> 4</td>
        <td class="center">X</td>
        <td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even gradeC">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>3rd june</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5</td>
        <td class="center">C</td>
        <td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>3rd june</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5.5</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
        <td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
       </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the jQuery datepicker function on the new rows you have added.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the datepicker again on datatable callback function

```
 oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
         "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

         }
     });
```